# Creating a private Polkadot Blockchain using Node Template

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Hello Guys I have just started development on polkadot and have went through their documents and tutorials, I want to build a private parachain that is open to other node which can connect given they have permissions. For now using their starter node template I was able to start a private blockchain on a server but I couldn't configure it so that it would allow any machine on any network to be able to connect to it. In short it wasn't discoverable by other machines. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Hvae you checked this tutorial ? https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/build-permission-network/

Maybe it gets you going with your idea

Comment: In the tutorial they are running the subnodes on the same machine on a seperate terminal I want the nodes to be able to connect to the main node from outside the local network, couldn't find any help in this tutorial related to that idea.

Comment: You just need to expose the ports and manage firewall restrictions properly (if needed) so nodes can discover each other like you would do, for instance, to expose a web server outside your local network.

Comment: any reference or reading material I can look into